# Нужно ли выделять запятыми "по капризу судьбы"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

В общем, есть текст:

> Опять же по капризу судьбы первым попавшимся человеком окажется
>   редкостный мошенник.

"Опять же" стоит там из-за того, что до этого в тексте было про череду невезений. "По капризу судьбы" автор в оригинале выделил запятыми. Но мне это кажется избыточным. Оставлять или нет?

Comment: К ответу добавлено примечание об отсутствии запятых.

Comment: Большое спасибо, я уже увидела. Благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, автор хотел выделить этот оборот. При постановке запятых логическое ударение падает на данную фразу:
*ОпЯть же, по капризу судьбЫ, первым попавшимся человеком окажется редкостный мошЕнник.* || Обстоятельства так можно обособлять, чтобы акцентировать на них внимание. Это здесь уместно, так как данная фраза не является ординарной. Отталкиваться следует от задуманных ударений при чтении. Но если это сочетание раньше встречалось в тексте, то обособление точно не к месту.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=112 (Тема: обстоятельства, выраженные существительными)

Если *опять же* вводное, то оно имеет значение *в добавление к сказанному, к тому же, кроме того*. Это как сокращение от *опять же надо заметить [замечу]*. Но здесь обычное значение *снова, ещё раз* тоже подходит.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_881

Уместно добавить *будто*: *будто по капризу судьбы*.

Примечание: Если вообще без запятых, то получается *ещё раз [снова] по капризу судьбы*. А если об этом капризе ранее не говорилось, то такая формулировка не сильно логична. Здесь больше похоже на то, что автор хочет ознакомить читателя с этим сочетанием, а не рассчитывает, что читающий догадается, о чём речь.

Comment: Меня тогда интересует вопрос: возможен ли вариант без запятых здесь? Ну чисто теоретически, при других интонациях.

Comment: Возможен, так как *по капризу судьбы* не является вводным.

Answer (score 1):

> "Опять же" стоит там из-за того, что до этого в тексте было про череду невезений.

В этом случае "опять же" больше похоже на вводное — вряд ли здесь подходит замена на обстоятельство "снова".

**По капризу судьбы** выделять не нужно. Предлагаю сторговаться с автором и оставить одну запятую из двух.

Answer (score 0):

"Меня тогда интересует вопрос: возможен ли вариант без запятых здесь? **Ну чисто теоретически, при других интонациях".**

Ответ:

**Невозможен.** Простое предложение (без обособления) должно делиться на две интонационно-смысловые части по схеме тема — рема. А это предложение разделить на такие части весьма проблематично. Его не прочитаешь с листа, так как нужно будет искать, где сделать паузу. Смысл и интонация не определяются сразу.

Интонационный и смысловой анализ следует рассматривать как единое целое и не считать, что эти принципы могут существовать раздельно. А то получается, что   в одном случае проверяем ударение, в другом — ищем логику, в третьем — вспоминаем про обязательные правила и т.д.